# Summary with flexbox and pseudo element fails to show inline in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari

In Safari 14 my example below shows like this

[image]

But if you use Chrome 87 for example it shows like this

[image]

I haven't found if this is a known issue? If it is, are there any suggested workarounds?

```css
summary::-webkit-details-marker {
  display: none
}

details {
  width: 300px;
}

summary {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  justify-content: space-between;
  outline: solid 4px #000;
  align-items: baseline;
}

summary::after {
  content: "";
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>Hello</summary>
</details>
```

Comment: try adding the -webkit- prefix for flex rules.

Comment: Sorry, I already tried that one. Updated the snippet with webkit prefixes.

Comment: try `-webkit-box-orient: horizontal;` for `summary`

Comment: Sorry, it has no effect.

Comment: did you manage to solve the problem?

Comment: No, not yet unfortunately

Comment: try "playing" with flex rules in the safari object inspector in real time. For example, for a pseudo-class `:after`, specify an inline flex display with a prefix, or il `flex: 1 1 auto` etc.

Comment: I found out the answer and updated the question with an answer and a workaround

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Problem**

Certain HTML elements, like `<summary>`, `<fieldset>` and `<button>`, do not work as flex containers. The browser's default rendering of those element's UI conflicts with the display: flex declaration.

**Workaround**

The simple solution to this problem is to use a wrapper element that can be a flex container (like a `<span>`) directly inside of the element that can't.