# Display flex with ::before pseudo not working on Safari

Tags: css, sass

Using display flex on pseudo-elements seem to not work on Safari. On Chrome this does work. Does anyone know a fix for Safari. Or happen to know why this not works on Safari?

I am using details summary HTML elements to use it as an accordion.

Output on chrome (V94):

[image]

Output on Safari (V14.1)

[image]

My css/scss code:

```
.product-metafield{ 
    summary{
        display: -webkit-box; 
        display: -ms-flexbox; 
        display: -webkit-flex; 
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row-reverse;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        gap: 10px;

        &::-webkit-details-marker{
            display: none;
        }
    }

    summary::before{
        font-size: 23px;
        line-height: 25px;
        content: "\002B"; // Plus
    }

    details[open] summary::before{
        font-size: 23px;
        line-height: 25px;
        content: "\2212"; // Minus
    }
    
}
```

HTML Snippet (Liquid/Shopify)

```
      <div class="product-size-guide product-metafield">
        <details>
            <summary>
              <p class="product-metafield-title">Size guide</p>
            </summary>
          <div class="size-guide-content">
            <img src="{{product.metafields.my_fields.size_guide | img_url: '500x'}}"
              alt="Size guide" id="sizeGuideContent">
          </div>
        </details>
      </div>
```

Comment: Please add an HTML example that showcases the issue, in the form of a StackOverflow snippet.

Comment: @connexo found same question with same problem https://stackoverflow.com/q/65301531/10601999

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just used for my use case `position: absolute;` on `summary::before` and moved the paragraph to the right with `margin-left: 20px;`

Found same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65301531/10601999), with answer stating

> Certain HTML elements, like `<summary>`, `<fieldset>` and `<button>`, do not work as flex containers. The browser's default rendering of those elements UI conflicts with the display: flex declaration.

The updated code:

```
.product-metafield{ 
    summary{
        &::-webkit-details-marker{
            display: none;
        }
    }

    summary::before{
        position: absolute;
        font-size: 23px;
        line-height: 25px;
        content: "\002B"; // Plus
    }

    details[open] summary::before{
        font-size: 23px;
        line-height: 25px;
        content: "\2212"; // Minus
    }
    
}

.product-metafield-title{
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

HTML Snippet (Liquid/Shopify)

```
      <div class="product-size-guide product-metafield">
        <details>
            <summary>
              <p class="product-metafield-title">Size guide</p>
            </summary>
          <div class="size-guide-content">
            <img src="{{product.metafields.my_fields.size_guide | img_url: '500x'}}"
              alt="Size guide" id="sizeGuideContent">
          </div>
        </details>
      </div>
```